# Can't ask questions

Tags: support

For some reason I can't ask any questions. It lets me type it up but when I click "submit", nothing happens.

Why is this?

Have I gone over my quota?

Answer (score 2):

In one month you can ask at most 50 questions including deleted questions. So you have to wait a few days.

Comment: or use an unregistered open ID if too necessary.

Comment: How do I check if I have asked my $50$ questions in the month?

Comment: Certainly do not use an unregistered openID to circumvent the rules! That's considered one of the most serious breach of rules, and is grounds for a lengthy suspension.

Comment: @Alex: so he can ask a friend to type and send the necessary question to circumvent circumventing rules!

Comment: As I've said many times before: if you're at the situation where you have to ask that many questions, you might want to pause and mull over them, or maybe even ask a real person at your nearest institution.